# Bash > how to call a program with an option, and the option use a variable containing double quotation

Tags: bash, special-characters

I call a program in bash like:
./program $OPTION

I used an option, for instance OPTION="--executor-cores 10 --executor-memory 11", in this way it is working pretty fine,

But if the option contains quotation mark, the bash can not parse it anymore. For instance, OPTION is: --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions="-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:-ResizePLAB"

In this case the bash just can not recognize the option as it contains double quotations. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you post your script?

Comment: See BashFAQ #50, which is directly on point: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a scalar variable (a single string) to store a list of strings. That is to say, the following won't reliably work for arbitrary data, for reasons explained at length in [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050), and touched on below<sup>[1]</sup>:

```
OPTION="--executor-cores 10 --executor-memory 11"
yourprogram $OPTION
```

---

Instead, use an array -- a data type natively built to store a list of strings:

```
options=( --executor-cores 10 --executor-memory 11 )
yourprogram "${options[@]}"
```

...which will work correctly even with complex options:

```
options=(
  --executor-cores 10
  --executor-memory 11
  --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions="-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:-ResizePLAB"
)
yourprogram "${options[@]}"
```

---

<sup>[1]</sup> - Bash parsing happens in phases, and the phase where quotes are parsed as syntax happens **before** the parts where variable expansions take place -- so after parameter expansion (replacing `$OPTION` with its contents) has happened, it's too late in the process for quotes to be honored. (That's true unless you use `eval` to go back to the very beginning of the parsing process -- but doing that introduces a host of bugs, security-related and otherwise; see also [BashFAQ #48](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)).

This is a feature, not a bug: Were it otherwise, writing secure code in bash handling data from untrusted sources would be nearly impossible.

Comment: This is great help! Thanks a lot!!!